# Php rows from db duplicating

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, while-loop, rows

Hey i have problem i need get all rows to variable $url but i get only the last row

```
$sql="SELECT kanalas FROM ikelti_vartotojai ORDER BY id";

if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {

  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){  
    $allchannels= $row[0];
    }  
}

$url = 'https://ids.com/?id='.$allchannels.'';

echo $url;
```

Comment: Didn't I see this similar post earlier? Edit: Right https://stackoverflow.com/q/52742863/ no idea why you deleted and reposted.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Hint: If you really want *all* channels you need an array, not a single variable you keep replacing over and over.

Comment: You are overwritting `$allchannels`. Use an array or concatenate the string.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte that's what Mario said in their deleted question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52742863/ but you can't see it though. Edit: *"You are overwriting $url in the loop. Your echo only occurs once after the loop. – mario 2 hours ago"* and *"You are setting $url on every iteration, so only the last one will actually be set. What exactly do you want to happen? Do you want a string full of URL's, or an array of URL's? Just echo the URL's? – GrumpyCrouton 2 hours ago"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){  
  $allchannels= $row[0];
}
```

into

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){  
  $allchannels[] = $row[0];
}
```

now `$allchannels` is an array containing `$row[0]` elements.
If You want to have URLs in array just add them before pushing:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){  
  $allchannels[] = 'https://ids.com/?id=' .$row[0];
}
```

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in this line -> $allchannels[] = $row[0];

Comment: but how to all rows get? like ?id=1463,23463,2343,46574,5423,6123

Comment: use `$allchannels[] = $row[0];` in a while loop, and set `$url = 'https://ids.com/?id=' .implode(',', $allchannels);`